# HTML + CSS: customise tabs or button groups with images

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to achieve the UI like Snapchat

They have 4 categories which display on 4 buttons
[image]

When user click on any button, it will be toggled and update the content below.

I thought about tabs or button groups. But I have no idea how to customise it with image like Snapchat.

Maybe my approach is not good one, welcome any better approach.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: any tabs plugin will allow you to use what you want in the tab selector, just use css to use a background image for them.  however this question is way too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are two things.

1. Tab Panel of some sort
2. How you can toggle a background image.

Both are actually pretty simple to do with jQuery or JavaScript.
Here is an example on how to make something along those lines. I recommend you reading the comments so you have an idea of what is going on.

```js
function toggleTab(element, tabname) {
  // Select all tab panels and hide them
  var tabPanels = $('.panel');
  // Loop through every element and hide it by changing the display to none
  for (var i =0; i < tabPanels.length; i++) {
    $(tabPanels[i]).css('display', 'none');
  }
  // Now that we hid everything we can show the user the element that they clicked on.
  // We select the panel that has the ID of tabname
  $('#' + tabname).css('display', 'block');

  // For toggling styling
  var tabButtons = $('.button');
  for (var i =0; i < tabButtons.length; i++) {
    $(tabButtons[i]).removeClass('toggled');
  }
  $(element).addClass('toggled');
}
```

```css
#buttoncontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  /* Background-color can also be background-image */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 160);
}

/* This class will only apply to the div of the active tab panel */
.toggled {
  /* Background-color can also be background-image */
  background-color: lime !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttoncontainer">
  <div class="button" onclick="toggleTab(this, 'step1')">Step 1</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="toggleTab(this, 'step2')">Step 2</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="toggleTab(this, 'step3')">Step 3</div>
</div>

<div id="step1" class="panel">
  <h2>Step 1</h2>
  <p>This is step 1</p>
</div>

<div id="step2" class="panel" style="display:none">
  <h2>Step 2</h2>
  <p>This is step 2</p>
</div>

<div id="step3" class="panel" style="display:none">
  <h2>Step 3</h2>
  <p>This is step 3</p>
</div>
```

I'm sure that you can figure it out for yourself from here. The only thing left to do really is making the proper styling for it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it sounds simple.

Comment: @PeterPham check my updated answer. I'm sure it answers your question and gives you a good idea on how to do this. If my answer helped / answered your question don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: my big thank to you. it's simply what I need.